# Best way to change image base URL in Magento

Tags: php, magento

What is the best way to change image base URL on Magento?
For example for adding a prefix to the URL, I tried changed the `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Media/config.php` file to this:

```
public function getBaseMediaUrl()
{
    return "myurlprefix".Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'catalog/product';
}
```

However, this doesn't affect all URLs.

My Magento version is 1.9x

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have a doubt?. Why you are changing the url?...Can you please let me know your base url?...If you want to put CDN url?